# Peewee ORM - annotate count on many-to-many relation even if count is 0

Tags: python, sql, orm, peewee

Let's try to explain my problem using users and tweets.

These are my models (from Peewee docs):

```
class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField()

class Tweet(BaseModel):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='tweets')
    message = TextField()
```

and this is my query:

```
User.select().annotate(Tweet).order_by(fn.Count(Tweet.id).desc())
```

I have some users that haven't already tweeted, but I'd like anyway to get them with my query. Unfortunately, this query doesn't work for users without tweets.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is a one-to-many relation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved.

If you have my problem, simply use `OUTER JOIN`.

Here is my new query:

```
User.select(User, fn.Count(Tweet.id).alias('count')) \
    .join(Tweet, JOIN_LEFT_OUTER).group_by(User)
```